# ITMS-9000 "element "img" not allowed here; expected..."

Tags: epub

Trying to get an ePub file to pass through Apple's ePub checker but get two errors multiple times.

(1) element "img" not allowed here; expected the element...

This is the coding on the page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="../Styles/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Tokyo</h2>
<p>Japan is made up of five main islands: Hokkaido, Honshu, Shikoku, Kyushu, and Okinawa. Over three-quarters of the 127 million people in Japan live on Honshu, the largest and most developed island. Tokyo, the capital, lies on its eastern shore.</p>
<img alt="Tokyo Metropolis" src="../Images/Tokyo-Metropolis.jpg"/>
<p>Tokyo Metropolis, one of Japan’s 47 prefectures, is comprised of two areas: the <a class="hook" id="Special-Wards-23">23 special wards</a>, which together make up what most consider to be Tokyo, and the rest—the cities and towns that lie to the west. It is best thought of as a constellation of cities that have, over the course of time, merged into one vast urban sprawl which is home to over 13 million people.</p>
```

I have the alt tag inserted correctly and it displays correct in iBooks.

CSS for img is as follows:

```
img
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 1px;
border: 1px solid #021a40;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I've looked around at numerous forums but am none the wiser as to why I'm getting this error.

(2) Same error but in relation to  tags ("element "ul" not allowed here; expected end-tag or element "li"...")

Html here...

```
<ul>
<li><a href="../Text/Introduction.xhtml"><b>Introduction</b></a></li>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="../Text/Tokyo.xhtml">Tokyo</a></li>
    <li><a href="../Text/A%20Brief%20History.xhtml">A Brief History</a></li>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="../Text/A%20Brief%20History.xhtml#The-Emergence-of-Japan">The Emergence of Japan</a></li>
```

[Html cut short as it is a table of contents and long].

I think this is because I have nested lists, but this works perfectly in iBooks so I don't know why it is causing an error at validation.

I'd be very grateful for some help!

Answer (score 2):

The second one is clear: lists can only contain list items. That's how it is.
You say "this works perfectly in iBooks" but that's not true. It doesn't work perfectly. It's just that the app's error handling routines happen to handle this in such a way that the result looks roughly like what you expected. This will not be the same on other machines, other versions of the app etc. Avoid such errors.

The first error message is more subtle.
What version of HTML does the file identify itself as?
If it's XHTML 1.x or HTML 4.x strict, then plain text and inline elements are officially not allowed at the body level. Don't ask me why, I don't know.
If the file version is HTML 4.01 Transitional or HTML5 (or the XHTML equivalents) then images as children of the body are fine.

If anybody can tell me why this difference exists, I'd be delighted!

As for a solution, if you can't change the HTML version to HTML5 or XHTML5, then simply putting everything in the body in one big div will do the trick. Just put `<div>` right after the `<body>` and `</div>` just before the `</body>`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I solved the issue by trial and error but my problems were exactly as you kindly laid out above.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered, then. Thank you.